# QGIS Georeferencer - Coordinates Rounding Too Small

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have an image I'm trying to georeference on my map, but am having an issue with the coordinates which are sent to the map from the georeferencer.

As you can see below in the image, the yellow boxes above each point each show the correct location where the points should be referenced to. An example being 37.2317089 rather than 37.23 as shown in the table in the picture below.

Is there a way to increase the amount of digits after the decimal point?

Or do you have any suggestions for any other ways of going about this?

[image]

Comment: It is a bug but it should have been fixed https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10480. However, the comment in the bug suggests that internally the full accuracy has been used all the time.